# Spring Security redirect to https

Tags: java, spring-boot, ssl, spring-security, undertow

I'm starting my application with Spring Boot on http server port 11218 and I have Undertow https listener which listen port 8090. Ssl is working fine, but I can't redirect from 11218 port to 8090. I tried to use Spring Security but received

> **org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException**:
> **Request method 'GET' not supported  at**
> org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping.handleNoMatch(RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping.java:213)
> at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.lookupHandlerMethod(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:422)
> at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.getHandlerInternal(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:367)
> at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping.getHandlerInternal(RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping.java:110)
> at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping.getHandlerInternal(RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping.java:59)
> at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMapping.getHandler(AbstractHandlerMapping.java:395)
> at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.getHandler(DispatcherServlet.java:1234)
> at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1016)
> at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
> at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
> at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
> at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:645)     at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
> at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:750)     at
> io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:74)
> at
> io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:129)
> at
> ru.openbank.platform.filters.MDCFilter.doFilterInternal(MDCFilter.java:55)
> at
> org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
> at
> io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61).

**Request:**
http://127.0.0.1:11218/encashment/send

**Spring Security:**

```
private void redirect(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.requiresChannel()
     .mvcMatchers("/encashment/send")
     .requiresSecure()
     .and().portMapper().http(11218).mapsTo(8090);
}
```

**Undertow configuration:**

```
 @SneakyThrows
    @Bean
    public UndertowServletWebServerFactory undertowServletWebServerFactory() {
        UndertowServletWebServerFactory undertowServletWebServerFactory = new UndertowServletWebServerFactory();

        KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
        trustStore.load(new FileInputStream(trustStoreFile), trustStorePassword.toCharArray());

        KeyManagerFactory keyManagerFactory =
                KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
        keyManagerFactory.init(trustStore, trustStorePassword.toCharArray());

        TrustManagerFactory trustManagerFactory =
                TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
        trustManagerFactory.init(trustStore);

        SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        sslContext.init(keyManagerFactory.getKeyManagers(),
                trustManagerFactory.getTrustManagers(),
                new SecureRandom());

        undertowServletWebServerFactory.addBuilderCustomizers(new UndertowBuilderCustomizer() {

            @Override
            public void customize(Undertow.Builder builder) {
                builder.addHttpsListener(additionalPort, "127.0.0.1", 
                sslContext).setHandler(path().addPrefixPath("/encashment", websocket(
                        (exchange, channel) -> {
                            channel.resumeReceives();
                        })));

            }
        });

        return undertowServletWebServerFactory;
    }
```

My Controller:

```
@PostMapping("/send")
@ApiOperation("Передача информации об инкасации на Тибко")
public JsonItem<EncashmentInfoResponse> sendEncashmentInfo(@Valid @RequestBody EncashmentInfoDto encashmentInfoDto) {
    encashmentInfoDto.setPersonId(authenticationUtil.getPersonId());
    return encashmentService.sendEncashmentInfo(encashmentInfoDto);
}
```

Comment: The stack trace appears to be related to Spring MVC. What makes you think it's something to do with your security configuration?

Comment: With my Spring MVC everything is ok. I have updated question